# Two-way databinding Angular 2 error with strings

Tags: angular

all. Problem with send string format between two components.

I create children components

filters-panel.component.ts

```
`@Component({
  selector: 'as-filters-panel',
  templateUrl: './filters-panel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filters-panel.component.css']
})
export class FiltersPanelComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {

   filterByName:string;
   @Output() searchNameChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

  categories : Category[];
  subscribe : Subscription;

  constructor(public categoryService : CategoryService, public router : Router) {

  }

  @Input() get filterName() {
    console.log(this.filterByName);
    return this.filterByName;
  }

  set filterName(val) {
    this.filterByName = val;
    this.searchNameChange.emit(this.filterByName);
  }

  onNameChange(model: any) {
    this.filterName = model;
  }`
```

and html template

```
  <input class="filterInput" type="text" [ngModel]="filterName" (ngModelChange)= "onNameChange($event)">
```

In parent component i try to get filterName

```
<as-filters-panel [(filterName)]="filterNameField" [(selectedSort)]="sortByField"></as-filters-panel>
```

and create filterNameField:string = ''; in .ts file
It doesnt work with string, but if i try to send number, works good

Comment: why do want to explicitly trigger the event ngModelChange?? give more information of what is your expectation?

Comment: i want to receive data from input field, need text value

Comment: where is the input field in your component?

Comment: in filter.panel.component.html

Comment: if my understanding is correct, you have filter panel component and child component that contains the filter criteria fields as textbox, dropdown, etc and you want the textbox value in filter panel component correct?

Comment: filter-panel is a child component, i want to send input value to parent component to use in filter

Comment: I shall update you the code in sometime. hang on

Comment: did you try this : `onNameChange(model: string) {
    this.filterName = model;
  }`. Also, you can get rid of `onNameChange` this way `<input class="filterInput" type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterName">` to avoid type mismatch

Answer (score 0):

I found mistake. 
filterByName:string;
@Output() searchNameChange = new EventEmitter();

must be 
filterByName:string;
@Output() filterByNameChange = new EventEmitter();